# I am struggling to get started with a Stack and Queue and was wondering if anyone could help based on these Classes?

Tags: class, stack, queue

```
#include <iostream>;

using namespace std;

class Node
    {
public:
    Node(int value, Node* nextptr = NULL, Node* prevptr = NULL, int currentpriority = 0);
    int getVal(void);
    Node* getNext(void);
    Node* getPrev(void);
    void setVal(int value);
    void setPrev(Node* prevptr);
    void setNext(Node* nextptr);
    int getPriority(void);
    void setPriority(int priority);
private:
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    int priority;
    int value;
};

class Stack
    {
public:
     Stack(void);
    ~Stack(void);
    void Push(int value);
    Node* NodePop(void);
    int Pop(void);
    private:
    Node* top;
};

class Queue
    {
public:
    Queue(void);
    ~Queue(void);
    void Enqueue(int i, int priority = 0);
    int Dequeue(void);
    protected:
    Node* back;
    Node* front;
private:
    virtual Node* NodeDequeue(void);
    };
```

So these are the classes we have been given I am struggling to just get the ball rolling in a sense. I have done a simple stack last year with pointers and Templates but I am having trouble figuring out where to start with the added feature of the get and set functions. I am only allowed to use iostream also as a heads up.